# How to dispatch using phonetic keyboard to convert from English to my desired language?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, dispatchevent

I am using Ckeditor, and I want to convert English to my desired language using phonetic character conversion.
I have successfully converted it but the dispatched event on the target is not showing me a new character to edit.

```
newEvent.initKeyEvent("keypress", true, true, window,false, false, false, false, 0, codes[whichChar]);
e.target.dispatchEvent(newEvent);
```

The console is showing me this:

```
keypress { target: <body.cke_editable.cke_editable_themed.cke_contents_ltr.cke_show_borders>, key: "", charCode: 1726, keyCode: 0 }
```

And also dispatched event returns true but does not show anything in the editor and the target is also correct.